# CheckBox (event) method for "checked = false"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any method or Is it possible to write a method to execute a set of instructions when a **(Windows Form)** checkbox is unchecked (but not when checked)? I will clarify this providing my sample code.

**Existing Sample Code:**

```
private void ChkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ChkBox.Checked == false)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("unchecked");
        }
}
```

**Q:** Could that `if condition` be avoided by writing a method for this which gets executed only when checkbox is unchecked.

**Illustration:**
Something like this:

```
private void ChkBox_Unchecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("unchecked");
}
```

**additional comments:** I don't have anything to execute for event 'checkbox is checked' .. So just thinking if I can avoid `checkchanged` event by replacing it with `unchecked` type of event.

Comment: winforms, wpf, asp.net?

Comment: There is no such a thing because it's useless.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, windows forms

Comment: @GeekWorking then see my solution below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need that strange events, then create custom check box by inheriting from CheckBox. Override it's `OnCheckedChanged` event, and add your `Unchecked` event:

```
public class StrageCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public event EventHandler Unchecked;

    protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCheckedChanged(e);

        if (!Checked)
            OnUnchecked(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnUnchecked(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Unchecked != null)
            Unchecked(this, e);
    }
}
```

Use `StrangeCheckBoxes` instead of default check boxes. Subscribe to `Unchecked` event. Voila, you have that strange behavior.

**Remark** Actually I would not suggest usage of custom control or if/else in all scenarios. If you have many checkboxes with this kind of behavior, then custom control is better than many duplicated if/else in each handler. If you have several controls, or single handler for all checkboxes, then I'd go with if/else approach.

Comment: Didn't downvote (actually advocated above), but 'envious'? Seems... presumptuous and judgmental.

Comment: @GrantThomas that's how I call downvoters which don't leave comments and downvote working answers. Only reason for such actions I see is envy. Isn't it? :)

Comment: Agreed! if not now .. can be used for future reference.. handy code.. thanks for sharing..

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry. That's the only event you can trigger for a state change. Your code looks fine.
Any reason you don't like it?

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit the `CheckBox` and `override OnCheckedChanged`

```
class ExtendedCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public event EventHandler Unchecked;
    protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCheckedChanged(e);

        if (Checked == false)
            OnUnchecked(e);            
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the worst way of doing it; as I suggested, you could expose two _new_ events to distinguish the state and fire them on `CheckedChanged` accordingly, without essentially swallowing the false-state alerts.

Comment: @GrantThomas - can you be little more specific?

Comment: +1 For something that covers the original question, but it seems like overkill for the scenario. If the performance of a bool compare is so tight to make a difference the OP would probably have to do a speed comparison with virtual method calls!

Comment: @AppDeveloper Check out lazyberezovsky's answer.

Comment: @AppDeveloper now your answer looks like copy of mine :)

Comment: The way this answer has changed seems very much like misconduct.

Comment: @AppDeveloper You just seem to be clutching at straws; you gave no original explanation and give no elaboration for your 'enhancement', due to the benefit of others.

Comment: @AppDeveloper with all respect, but this time it was me who downvoted. For copying answer and then changing it to not-working version

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - its ok! i get it!

Answer (score 1):

No, the only event exposed is one to detect when a change to the state occurred, then you must check the state to determine how it changed.

You could, if so inclined, create your own control which essentially wraps this one and exposes such state-distinguishing events, but this seems entirely pointless.

Comment: Thank you.. yes an if else is better than that complicated approach!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the event is fired on all changes, you could write your own control which differentiates the value selected and raises separate events but not sure it is really worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do something like this, but if you have many instructions to execute if the checkbox was unchecked and you don't want to encapsulate them in an `if` statement you could check for `checked` at the beginning and return:

```
private void ChkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ChkBox.Checked) return;

    MessageBox.Show("unchecked");
}
```

Comment: Personally, I never understood why people use "`== true`" in comparisons.

Comment: Now it's better:). I've just copy-paste'd the code and replaced "false" with "true".

Answer (score 0):

This will be a simple straight forward solution although the best suggested way will be to inherit from the CheckBox and modify the events. But, a relatively simple way is as follows:

Reduce the `CheckBox` width so that the `CheckBox Label` is no longer visible. Only the box should be visible. Then, include another label beside the box which should be mutually exclusive from the box.

Now, edit the `CheckBox Clicked` event. Use some sort of a flag to identify the state of the checkbox. Voila!